# XLM.transforming HTML with XLS

Tags: xml, xslt

I need help.

I have a xml file like this :

```
<conferences>
  <conference>
    <edition>
      <titre>Titre 1</titre>
      <date>2005</date>
    </edition>
</conference>
<conference>
    <edition>
      <titre>Titre 2</titre>
      <date>2004</date>
    </edition>
</conference>
<conference>
    <edition>
      <titre>Titre 1</titre>
      <date>2001</date>
    </edition>
</conference>
<conference>
    <edition>
      <titre>Titre 2</titre>
      <date>2001</date>
    </edition>
</conference>
<conference>
    <edition>
      <titre>Titre 3</titre>
      <date>2002</date>
    </edition>
</conference>
</conferences>
```

I wants to get it :

Titre 1 : 2005 2001

Titre 2 : 2004 2001

Titre 3 : 2002

I have a XSL file.
I arrive to don't have title duplicates like this :

```
 <xsl:key name="product" match="conferences/conference/edition/titre" use="." />
<xsl:template match="conferences">

<h1> Sommaire des conférences </h1>
<xsl:for-each select="conference/edition/titre[generate-id() = generate-id(key('product',.)[1])]">
    <p>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </p>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

but I don't see how view the dates, can someone help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:key name="product" match="conferences/conference/edition/titre" use="." />

<xsl:template match="/conferences">
    <h1> Sommaire des conférences </h1>
    <xsl:for-each select="conference/edition/titre[generate-id() = generate-id(key('product',.)[1])]">
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('product', .)">
                <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="../date"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </p>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```